# How to login to site using python's mechanize library?

Tags: python

I want to login to my router's site - http://192.168.0.1 and then I want to reboot my router. Is this possible? If it is how do I do it?

Comment: NO (with mechanize) if your modem used java !

Answer (score 1):

Someone already answered no, but offered no alternatives. You can try using [Telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-example), or if you must do it through the web UI, use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)